# Cannot pass arguments to script script

Tags: bash, shell

I try to pass an argument to a shell script.

This is my script `script.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo DOBS_TOKEN: $DOPS_TOKEN
if [[ -z "$DOPS_TOKEN" ]]; then
    echo "DOBS_TOKEN" is missing
    exit 1;
fi
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
DOBS_TOKEN=123 ./script.sh
```

Output:

```
DOBS_TOKEN:
DOBS_TOKEN is missing
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The variable in the script is called `$DOPS_TOKEN`, but the variable you set is called `$DOBS_TOKEN`.

```
B ≠ P
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this was the most stupid question on SO ;)

Comment: Questions like this should just be closed as typos with a comment, answers aren't useful to the community.

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler Don't feel bad, you have *lots* of company. I see several questions like this every day.